# Simple photo gallery gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there any rails gem, that implements simple photo gallery.

The required features are following:

- organizing photos to albums;
- admin interface, that allows to upload several photos at once, edit title and description.

I've found http://balderapp.com/, but this is an app (not a gem). Also, it is quite heavy, because of tags, places etc. These models can interfer with existing things in my project.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know that site, when I need to find a gem, I always go to https://www.ruby-toolbox.com

Comment: Any new candidates for this question in 2015?

Answer (score 9):

Refer following

1. http://rubygems.org/gems/spud_photos.
2. http://rubygems.org/gems/gallerize.

Go with first one. Detailed documentation is here: https://github.com/gregawoods/spud_photos.

Comment: I have checked on many gallery gems, but they all look no longer maintained or come with no real examples. Has the paperclip gem taken over?